# Overriding Woocommerce child theme not working

Tags: templates, woocommerce, overriding

Overriding Woocommerce files from my child theme is not working at all. I am sure everything is 100% right, really frustrating. I am following every step in a video at this page:

> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it was so simple. Go to this path:

> WP Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> System Status -> Tools

and then uncheck the "Template debug mode":

[image: Woocommerce\system Status\tools]

Comment: Since WooCommerce 3 this setting isn't available anymore. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The documentation at the moment says to create a directory in you child theme's root that will contain the overiden templates i.e. your-child-theme/woocommerce/templates/your-overiden-file.php That didn't work for me; but what did was just placing the files/directories contained contained in woocommerce/templates directly into the child themes root. It may or may not be a supported work around but it did seem to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you @SurferJoe.  I am perplexed why the /woocommerce/ override directory is not working in the child theme though.  From a normal stand alone theme; it does work.

Comment: @SurferJoe and all:  The reason this does not work is the /templates/ directory in the child theme.  This article here sums it up perfectly.  Basically, when you put your child theme structure together, you do /your-child-theme/woocommerce/emails/tempate-here.com.  There is no 'templates' folder necessary.  Effectively move everything up one level.  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still interested in this topic I have found what was causing this issue on my theme. Just add the theme support for Woocommerce in functions.php as described on Github.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes

Comment: It didn't work. I had to change a word in email order details file in woocommerce. After updating the file with my change I uploaded the file with this structure in my child theme: 

mytheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php

But looks like adding them in child theme doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What you did is correct according to the documentation of WooCommerce, I don't know why it's not working. You can try using the hooks. You can find info about this topic at the end of this article https://woocommerce.com/posts/how-to-customize-emails-in-woocommerce/

Comment: A full list of WC hooks here https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: Ok. Checking these.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Template Debug Mode is no longer an option in `Woocommerce` system tools, this is what worked for me.

Just add this line to your `wp_config.php` file:

`define('WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false);`